# Replacing more than one line in the console in python

Tags: python, replace, console

I'm writing a program in python and I'd like to replace more than one line in the console with new text.

For example if I have 3 sentences printed to the console with:

```
print("Hello World!")
print("How are you!")
print("What's going on?")
```

Where each on is on a different line (and so has an `\n`).

How do I go about replacing all of this text when it displays in the console? I can't us `\r` in this situation due to the `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an old post, but I came across it and worked out a solution as well. Added a timer, because otherwise the print statements bury each other and you'll only be able to read the last one. I'm on python 2.7:

```
import os
import time

os.system("printf 'Hello World!'")
time.sleep(1)
os.system("printf '\rHow are you?!'")
time.sleep(1.5)
os.system("printf '\rWhats going on?'")
os.system("echo ")
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple fix would be to simply change the end separator for printing your strings. you can specify how you want the print function to separate calls with the `end` argument

```
print("hello world!", end="")
print("\rhello world again!")
```

In this case, we're setting the separator to "", which is nothing. So printing the next strings starts on the same line thus `\r` can be used. Compiling that gives you `hello world again!` on one line.

Comment: The question asked how to replace text on multiple lines of the console. This is only one line. Also, you don't compile python.